# My script for mute mic is not working, need thoughts and anwers

Tags: windows, automation, autohotkey, microphone

```
#NoEnv  
SendMode Input  
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir% 
#SingleInstance force

MuteMic() {
    local MM
    SoundSet, +1, MASTER:1, MUTE, 9 ; my mic is on 9
    SoundGet, MM, MASTER:1, MUTE, 9 ; my mic is on 9
    #Persistent   
    return
}
!Alt+m::MuteMic()
```

It does not work, here is my current drivers. I am currently on Windows 10 version 1803 (build 17134.1) My hot key is Alt+m. Thanks for the help and input! XD

Answer (score 0):

Master = Speakers, not your Mic, so in essence, you are muting your speakers, not your mic (I think).

What happens when you replace Master with Headphone or Microphone?  And also, are you able to move it from outlet #9 to something more direct like #1 or something?

I found this to see if you are REALLY on 9 or not, https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SoundSet.htm#Ex  but you may have run this already to determine it was on 9.

Answer (score 0):

Issues with your code:

1. Your hotkey definition
2. You don't need `#Persistent`, certainly not in a function in any case.

Try:

```
!m::
MuteMic() {
    SoundSet +1, Microphone:1, MUTE, 9 ; my mic is on 9
    SoundGet MM, Microphone:1, MUTE, 9 ; Why do you do this when you're not using it?
}
```

If you don't really need the value for `MM`, it could be further simplified to:

```
!m::SoundSet +1, Microphone:1, MUTE, 9
```